# Smooth keyframes without easing

Tags: animation, keyframes

How can I smooth out motion between keyframes, but without messing up other parts of the animation? I'd use bezier and I've tired messing with the handles and lerping types, but, as in the second image, it smooths out more than I want.

[image]

Just trying to get the one keyframe smoothed so the change in motion isn't instant/jagged, but not so much as to drastically change the rest of the animation.

[image]

For context it's a camera. It moves a bit, then changes direction to follow the motion of a character walking. Without smoothing, there's a jolt as the direction changes, but with the smoothing I've managed to do so far, it changes the motion after too much and the camera flies away off course.

Comment: I'm not sure this will solve your problem but you may not be aware the handles in the Graph Editor are by default, connected and thus can be a trifle restrictive.  Select the keyframe, then the handle in the Graph Editor and press V, then select "Free".  This will disconnect the twin handles and give you far more control.  I usually press VFG as a standard sequence to free them, the G to Grab the handle.

Comment: Further to the above... As for your camera lurching to swing to a new target, this could be because it just hasn't enough time to do it smoothly.  i.e. it needs more space between it's keyframes, starting earlier if it can.  The slower the action the easier it is to smooth it.

Comment: The issue isn't the movement of a camera from one keyframe to another, it's the change in speed and direction. Right now it snaps from one speed+direction to another, causing the 'snap' (as in a jolt because the change in direction isn't smoothed out).
I'm not after really 'smoothing' the animation, just smoothing the 'jolt' in the change in speed and direction. Smoothing it throws the rest off too much, and I'm finding it hard to get an accurate balance manually moving the handle. Thanks for the info, though.

Comment: From your description it sounds like the camera interpolation is set to "Constant".  I imagine it's not though as you have found handles with which to manipulate.  I've had a similar problem when a cam had to switch from being stationary to latching onto a passing object.  It was some years ago but I'll go dig that one out, see how I tamed it.

Comment: I have no proper idea what your scenario is but from what you tell me the jerk might be reduced effectively enough perhaps by allowing the target to 'get away' from the camera initially. (Tracking constraint's 'Influence' slider). Continued...

Comment: The archived file I mentioned was in fact a commercial animator involving a fast moving aircraft moving left to right and the cam's Bezier driven cam-tracking appearing far too machine-like for a human operator.  With nothing like Blender's features and the few frames available there was no way it could be smoothed out so the tracking was actually keyframed off for a few frames so the aircraft swept into view, 'unlocked'.   Cont...

Comment: This allowed it to get ahead of the cam and to the far side of the screen.   The tracking was then restored and the camera catching up again, but this time much smoother and appearing as though human operated.